# Status bar notification click event Android for background foreground app state

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

on click of a status bar notification.
i want to check that if my app is in foreground state then only notification will cancel or if my app is in background state it will open my app.
i have managed my app state using this code in my application class

```
public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
}

public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
}

private static boolean activityVisible;
```

and putting these for all my activities

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

for notification i am using this code

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_on).build();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                AppStartActivty.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

where shod i put this condition to check that app state and notification click behaviour.
sorry for my bad inglish

Comment: U want to check whether ur app is in foreground or background through notification , right?

Comment: @MSS yes and on click if my app is in background i want to open it otherwise notification cancel only

Comment: yeah u can do it by implementing service.

Comment: @MSS canyou please tell me procedure or any demo link for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your app is in Background/foreground using below code.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appInfo = (ArrayList)activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo app : appInfo) {
                Log.d(TAG, "App: " + app.processName + "    State: " + (app.importance == 100 ? "Foreground" : "Background"));
                if (app.processName.equals(YourApp().getPackageName())) {
                    Log.d(TAG, app.processName);
                    if (app.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                       // Cancel notification
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```